# What does "LFF SATA" mean?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, terminology

I've heard of SATA, but "LFF SATA" as listed on [HP's specs page](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF06a/15351-15351-4237916-4237918-4237917-4248009.html) *([archive](https://archive.fo/tf0Cp))* is a new one for me.

What does the "LFF" bit mean?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

LFF == Large Form Factor == 3.5" hard drive

SFF == Small Form Factor == 2.5" hard drive

They had to start designating it since many servers and even desktops now are shipping with SFF drives to save physical space and/or cram more drives in.

Comment: Of course, they could have just said 3.5" or 2.5" and everyone would have known what they were talking about without making new things up :)

Comment: I wish that were true...alas, in my experience, it is most certainly not.

Comment: That's really it?? Can I just cram a consumer 2.5" drive in one of those fancy SFF drive bays and it'd work? (I know of the reliability and such difference between server drives and consumer drives)

Comment: @VincentVancalbergh you're correct. Of course (for posterity and those who com after you) I will highly recommend *not* using consumer (aka: laptop) drives in server hardware, only use drives that were designed for the parameters of server hardware and lifecycles, and that includes firmware, as most consumer drives use firmware to maximize power efficiency and responsiveness, and not speed and reliability, especially important for RAID'd drives.

Answer (score 5):

To complement Peelman's answer, here is HP's official documentation on the topic of all the other disk vocabulary that goes with LFF and SFF:

[image]

[image]

Source/reference:

`HPE Hard Disk Drives - a00001287enw - 15825 - Worldwide - V10 - 13-August-2018`